# react native admob Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED error on run

Tags: android, react-native, admob

I'm testing react-native-admob library https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob with fresh RN project but when I run `react-native run-android` it show this error:

```
> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
E:\WORK\react\RN\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 20s
20 actionable tasks: 14 executed, 6 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

**packages:**

> "react-native": "0.59.9", "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.5"

Comment: Could you show me App.gradle??

Comment: @hongdevelop There is no App.gradle file! Where can I find it? sorry I'm not that good with native codes XD

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

you extend the `build.gradle`. adding other dependencies.

```js
dependencies {  
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'  
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'  
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'  
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'  
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'  
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'  
}
```

1. go to `node_module/react-native-admob/android`
2. open `build.gradle`

   `compileSdkVersion 28
   buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"`

Comment: same.. but when I also add `configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0"
force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0" } }` to `build.gradle` it compile but the app crash when start :/

Comment: as mentioned here: https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/issues/452

Comment: Does adding dependencies as my answer cause errors?

Comment: adding the dependencies alone shows the same error but with `configurations.all {...}` the app compile but crash at startup